# Replace a Field in a Space Delimited String C++

Tags: c++, string, delimiter

I have a single-space delimited string and I want to replace field x.

I can repeatedly use `find` to locate the x - 1 and x spaces, then use `substr` to grab the two strings on either side, then concatenate the two sub strings and my replacement text.

But man that seems like an awful lot of work for something that should be simple. Is there a better solution-- one that doesn't require Boost?

*Answer*
I've cleaned up @Domenic Lokies answer below:

```
sting fieldReplace( const string input, const string outputField, int index )
{
    vector< char > stringIndex( numeric_limits< int >::digits10 + 2 );
    _itoa_s( index, stringIndex.begin()._Ptr, stringIndex.size(), 10 );
    const string stringRegex( "^((?:\\w+ ){" ); //^((?:\w+ ){$index})\w+

    return regex_replace( input, regex( stringRegex + stringIndex.begin()._Ptr + "})\\w+" ), "$1" + outputField );
}
```

(`_itoa_s` and `_Ptr` are MSVS only I believe, so you'll need to clean those up if you want code portability. )

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since C++11 you should use a Regular Expression for your purposes. If you are not using a compiler which supports C++11, you can take a look at [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

Never combine `std::string::find` with `std::string::replace`, that is just not a good style in a language like C++.

I have written a short example for you to show you how to use Regular Expressions in C++.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string subject = "quick brown frog jumps over the lazy dog";
    std::regex pattern("frog");
    std::cout << std::regex_replace(subject, pattern, "fox");
}
```

Comment: I've selected this as the answer, cause I can get what I want. But no upvote cause this doesn't solve the generic case. I didn't know that C++11 had `regex_replace`, I can use that to generically capture and replace the xth word, but your solution requires that I know the word already, and I don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using one of the [`string::replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) methods:

- Locate the position of the `x-1`-st space. You can do it by calling `string::find` repeatedly
- Locate the position of the `x`-th space by calling `string::find` one more time
- Calculate the length of the word being replaced by subtracting the first index from the second one
- Call `string::replace` passing the first index, the length, and the replacement string.

Here is how you can implement this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "quick brown frog jumps over the lazy dog";
    size_t start = -1;
    int cnt = 3; // Word number three
    do {
        start = s.find(' ', start+1);
    } while (start != string::npos && --cnt > 1);
    size_t end = s.find(' ', start+1);
    s.replace(start+1, end-start-1, "fox");
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/AnkxMc)

Comment: +1 for taking the time to implement this, but, it's really exactly the code I wanted to avoid. @Domenic Lokies, doesn't really offer a complete solution, but I can dynamically create the regex to hold x-1 spaces, and thereby locate the word I'm looking for.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to clean up @Domenic Lokies answer in the question. Hopefully you'll agree that as long as C++11 is available that's the way to go.